# can not run the app written with cocos2d-iphone

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i have three layer a , b and c
main code of a：

```
-(id) init
{
    // always call "super" init
    // Apple recommends to re-assign "self" with the "super" return value
    if( (self=[super init] )) {
            CCSprite *sp = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg.png"];
            sp.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
            [self addChild:sp z:0 tag:1];

            [CCMenuItemFont setFontName: @"Georgia"];
            [CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:25];

            CCMenuItem *newGame = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"New Games" target:self selector:@selector(newGame:)];
            CCMenuItem *helpGame = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Help" target:self selector:@selector(helpGame:)];

            CCMenu *menulist = [CCMenu menuWithItems:newGame, helpGame, nil];
            [menulist alignItemsVertically];

            [self addChild:menulist z:1 tag:2];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) newGame:(id) sender
{
        CCScene *newscene = [CCScene node];
        [newscene addChild:[BScene node]];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionShrinkGrow transitionWithDuration:1.2f scene:newscene]];

}

- (void) helpGame:(id) sender
{
        CCScene *newscene = [CCScene node];
        [newscene addChild:[CScene node]];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionShrinkGrow transitionWithDuration:1.2f scene:newscene]];

}
```

the main code of b

```
    -(id) init
{
        if( (self=[super init] )) {
                CCSprite *sp = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg.png"];
                sp.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
                [self addChild:sp z:0 tag:1];

                [CCMenuItemFont setFontName: @"Georgia"];
                [CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:25];

                CCMenuItem *newGame = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"New Games" target:self selector:@selector(newGame:)];
                CCMenuItem *helpGame = [CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"Help" target:self selector:@selector(helpGame:)];

                CCMenu *menulist = [CCMenu menuWithItems:newGame, helpGame, nil];
                [menulist alignItemsVertically];

                [self addChild:menulist z:1 tag:2];
        }
        return self;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
        [super dealloc];
}

-(void) backCallback: (id) sender
{
        CCScene *sc = [CCScene node];
        [sc addChild:[AScene node]];

        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:  [CCTransitionShrinkGrow transitionWithDuration:1.2f scene:sc]];        
}
```

the problem is that the app will quit when i click the startGame for going into b,so how can i repair the code?thanks

Comment: Your code blocks seem improperly formatted, its make things very hard to read.  Can you re-format and then I would be happy to take a closer look at things with you.

Comment: OK，i have done,please have a look,thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that your button calls a unrecognized selector on self, because of this line:

```
[CCMenuItemFont itemFromString:@"New Games" target:self selector:@selector(newGame:)];
```

It appears that `-(void)newGame:(id)sender` is declared on another object, so you have to specify the correct object as the `target` parameter in the method above, or move the newGame function to b.